# Scala tuple extraction in function declaration

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Given for instance a `Tuple2` of the form

```
type Duple = (String,Int)
```

this function errs to extract and label the duple's items in the arguments,

```
def f( (s,n): Duple ): String = s*n
```

However this works,

```
def f( d: Duple ): String = {
  val (s,n) = d
  s*n
}
```

Is there a shorter form to extract and label a tuple's items in a function than this declarative approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a regular 2 arg function:

```
scala> val f: (String, Int) => String = (a, b) => a * b
f: (String, Int) => String = <function2>
```

convert it to single arg function that accepts tuples:

```
scala> val tf = f tupled
tf: ((String, Int)) => String = <function1>
```

call it with a tuple arg:

```
scala> tf("a" -> 2)
res0: String = aa
```

or if you going the opposite direction:

start with a function that takes a tuple:

```
scala> tf
res2: ((String, Int)) => String = <function1>
```

convert it to function that takes 2 args:

```
scala> val uf = Function.untupled(tf)
uf: (String, Int) => String = <function2>
```

call it with 2 args:

```
scala> uf("b", 3)
res3: String = bbb
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def f(d: Duple): String = d._1 * d._2

def f(d: Duple): String = d match { case (x, y) => x * y }
```